# images and buttons are not horizontally aligned

Tags: html, css

I have met some problems while doing a image-viewer project. The problem is that my buttons and the image are not following justify-content property, which they don't distributed equally inside my div block, how could it be solved? Also the image is not centered as the title does despite I set the align item property. I dow know how to fix that. I've searched over the website for solutions but none of them seems working.
Could anyone help me, please? Thanks in advance.

Here are the html and css code:

```
<div class="image-viewer__container">
            <div class="image-viewer__title">Image Viewer</div>
            <div class="image-viewer__main">
                <div class="image-viewer__button"><img src="./images/back.png" id="previous" /></div>
                <div class="image-viewer__display" style="background-image: url(./images/loading.gif);background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;">
                    <img src="https://scontent.ftpe7-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/p640x640/119893827_3212042898922322_5684339818610522875_o.jpg?_nc_cat=104&_nc_sid=730e14&_nc_ohc=fGG3wRqLaLEAX8MrIY-&_nc_ht=scontent.ftpe7-2.fna&tp=6&oh=36c5e163223a1e8abca79a2b3892c915&oe=5F976AFF" id="display">
                    <div class="image-viewer__display-source-wrapper">
                        <span><a href="https://scontent.ftpe7-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/p640x640/119893827_3212042898922322_5684339818610522875_o.jpg?_nc_cat=104&_nc_sid=730e14&_nc_ohc=fGG3wRqLaLEAX8MrIY-&_nc_ht=scontent.ftpe7-2.fna&tp=6&oh=36c5e163223a1e8abca79a2b3892c915&oe=5F976AFF" target="_blank">
                        https://scontent.ftpe7-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/p640x640/119893827_3212042898922322_5684339818610522875_o.jpg?_nc_cat=104&_nc_sid=730e14&_nc_ohc=fGG3wRqLaLEAX8MrIY-&_nc_ht=scontent.ftpe7-2.fna&tp=6&oh=36c5e163223a1e8abca79a2b3892c915&oe=5F976AFF</a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="image-viewer__button"><img src="./images/next.png" id="next" /></div>
            </div>
</div>
```

```
.image-viewer__container {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.image-viewer__title {
    font-size: 5rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #615dec;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

.image-viewer__main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin: auto;

}

.image-viewer__button {
    display: inline;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.image-viewer__button img {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.image-viewer__display {
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 3rem;
    max-width: 80rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 0.6rem;
}

.image-viewer__display-source-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 12px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    min-width: 100em;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
}

#display {
    object-fit: contain;
    width: 50rem;
    height: 30rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#source {
    display: inline;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: add `width : 100%;` to your container

Comment: @KALITA it is not working. The element inside the image-viewer__main block aren't distributed equally and i don't know why

Answer (score 2):

This is because you've set a fixed width to your image. By setting the main image to `100%` the image will fit and fill up the remaining space so the 3 elements are always distributed equally.

main image size = full width - both your arrows

**current**

```
    #display {
        object-fit: contain;
        width: 50rem; /*fixed width*/
        height: 30rem; /*fixed width*/
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
```

**amended**

```
    #display {
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
        width: 100%; /*was added*/
        height: auto; /*was added*/
    }
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1L2mvx4j/1/)

Comment: how is that affecting the justify content property? and the intention of setting fixed width is to have images in a suitable size. Also I found a new problem that the picture aren't center like the title does, how is that fixed?

Comment: By setting the main image to 100% the image will fit and fill up the remaining space so the 3 elements are always distributed equally. I just edited that to my answer as well. But when you set a fixed width to an emelent and when the screen width is smaller than the fixed width then flexbox can no longer distribute the child elements inside its parent element.So you don't see the desired result.

Comment: It only makes the image fill up the space but still not distributed evenly like the picture above, why is that?

Comment: You can't have an element that is wider than its parent to be able to distribute evenly. You can distribute only if the children are smaller than its parent (unless you want to have a overflow-x).

Comment: That was the case. So that's what I've changed in your code and enabled your 'justify-content' to work as expected.

Comment: I think I know the mistake, do you mean the image itself is larger than the block? Correct me if I'm wrong. so the "object-fit:contain;" can't reduce its size and make it smaller than the parent?

Comment: there you go! that's exactly what has happened :)

Comment: but the picture above is what it does after adding your code. I've done what you say but it looks not working, why is it working on your computer

Answer (score 0):

Add css `float:"right"` in css button.

Comment: Such an answer should go into comments section. If you want to answer,please provide more information explaining also why the specific solution should be used.

Comment: if you want to explain it ! Go to Google